# backbone.js: Prevent listener event from firing when model changes

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, model

I have the following listener in the view for when a model is changed:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
```

When I change the model :

```
model.set('foo', bar);
```

Is it possible to make it not trigger the listener event for this specific function call? I still want the event to trigger at other calls.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog):

> Generally speaking, when calling a function that emits an event (`model.set`, `collection.add`, and so on...), if you'd like to prevent the event from being triggered, you may pass `{silent: true}` as an option. Note that this is *rarely*, perhaps even never, a good idea. Passing through a specific flag in the options for your event callback to look at, and choose to ignore, will usually work out better.

So if you don't want that specific `set` call to trigger a change event then:

```
model.set('foo', bar, { silent: true });
```

Or tunnel some information to `render` using a custom option:

```
model.set('foot', bar, { ignore_this: true });
```

and adjust `render`:

```
render: function(options) {
    if(options && options.ignore_this)
        return;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why the former method is bad though? I actually implemented the latter method but I thought it wasn't as clean as it could be.

Comment: The problem with `silent` is that you don't always know who is listening. Using `options` is more targeted.

Comment: This is unsatisfying answer. Looks like a dirty hack. Is backbone that silly and has no way of delaying render until after several models have finished changing?